# What's the best way to implement a shell command into my java project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a JavaFX/ Maven project.
While developing I sometimes need some Java code to run just once.

In my special case I have a directory containing configuration or temp files on the user's disk. This directory and its files will be created by the app when a new user is starting the app for the first time. In production, it will never be necessary to delete these files.
But in development, I sometimes change something in the file generation code. For example when I'm adding new configuration options. To test that I have to delete the directory manually and let my application regenerate everything to check if it still works.

In my years of coding, I had cases like that several times. And what I used to do was creating a method for this special task. Then I'm calling it from the main method and run the app.

I am sure I am not the only one and I am sure there is a better possibility.

I thought of creating some kind of command for the terminal to run my method.
Maybe a configuration in my IntelliJ which would call the method.

Comment: Not knowing that much of maven, but in gradle you would simply write a task for it into the build script which you can execute on demand. I guess you can do the same in maven.

Comment: Thank you that already helps me a lot :)

Comment: I couldn't do it myself. So I figured out it's called "Mojo" what I want to create. I followed this guide https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html to set one.
I'm getting ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find my.group:artifactId:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
But how is it even supposed to! The artifact is the artifact itself! Also it looks like the tutorial guides to an app that's ONLY a plug